# Ask - this.props.onPress is not a function. (In 'this.props.onPress(e)', 'this.props.onPress' is "this.page1")

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react native and i want to put the destination page in my const. (I'm using router flux)
Can somebody help me to explain how to do the correct way since i'm always encounter error for this.props.onPress is not a function when "onpress" the menu.

Some of my sample code :

```
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';

const list2 = [
  {
    name: 'Amy Farha',
    avatar_url:
      'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg',
    subtitle: 'Vice President',
    linearGradientColors: ['#FF9800', '#F44336'],
    menu: 'this.page1',
  },
  {
    name: 'Chris Jackson',
    avatar_url:
      'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
    subtitle: 'Vice Chairman',
    linearGradientColors: ['#3F51B5', '#2196F3'],
    menu: 'this.page2',
  },
];

  page1() {
      Actions.page1()
  }


      <View style={styles.list}>
        {list2.map((l, i) => (
          <ListItem
            leftAvatar={{ title: l.name[0], source: { uri: l.avatar_url } }}
            key={i}
            onPress={l.menu}
            title={l.name}
            subtitle={l.subtitle}
            chevron
            bottomDivider
          />
        ))}
      </View>
```

Expected result : after rendering the list, i can click the menu and redirect to the designated page.

Comment: Because it's a string? You're going to have to change things a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In React-Native, OnPress expects an eventHandler to be a "function".

Where as, the property "menu" from object "l" is not a function. Hence, it throws an exception.

If you wish to have a dynamic function call in your component, try something like this.

```
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';

const list2 = [
  {
    name: 'Amy Farha',
    avatar_url:
      'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg',
    subtitle: 'Vice President',
    linearGradientColors: ['#FF9800', '#F44336'],
    menu: 'page1',
  },
  {
    name: 'Chris Jackson',
    avatar_url:
      'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
    subtitle: 'Vice Chairman',
    linearGradientColors: ['#3F51B5', '#2196F3'],
    menu: 'page2',
  },
];

class SomeClass extends Component {

  page1() {
      Actions.page1();
  }

  page2() {
    Actions.page2();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.list}>
        {list2.map((l, i) => (
          <ListItem
            leftAvatar={{ title: l.name[0], source: { uri: l.avatar_url } }}
            key={i}
            onPress={this[l.menu]}
            title={l.name}
            subtitle={l.subtitle}
            chevron
            bottomDivider
          />
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
}
```

Now, the functions 'page1' and 'page2' would be triggered accordingly.

Comment: that's very enlighten, thanks for sharing the knowledge!

Comment: Any time .. Happy coding